# How to cite a game and props invented by the researcher?

Tags: citations, thesis, graphics

I am editing a paper to comply with APA 6th edition standards for credits, citations, and references. But the situation described next is new to me, and I could not find a satisfactory answer in the manual.

The researcher invented a game specifically for the study. The game involves props that the researcher also invented (i.e.,as part of the game invented for the study).

The author did disclose that the game was invented for the study. However, because this game could be used for commercial or charitable purposes, it "feels like" it has an intellectual property aspect to it where the author should be credited at one or more places within the manuscript and not just on the title page.

For example, the paper has a picture of the props, but no credit. Should there be a credit, and what does it look like?

Similarly, should there be a citation (where?) and a reference for the game (what does it look like)? Currently there is no citation.

Comment: Is "the researcher" who invented the game the same as "the author"?

Comment: @Nate Eldredge - Yes, the researcher and the author are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Similarly, should there be a citation (where?) and a reference for the game (what does it look like)?

No, it is not necessary or expected.  Imagine if you replaced the game with an experiment.  Then the paper would describe the experiment/game, but not cite it.

If the game has a published manual, you could cite that as if it were a book or report.  If there are other publications about the game, you might cite them.  This does not appear to be the case.

The fact that the game is someone's intellectual property does not imply that you need a formal citation.  You cite sources of information.  There are many examples of intellectual property which are not sources.

You might mention who invented the game.

> For example, the paper has a picture of the props, but no credit. Should there be a credit, and what does it look like?

You should credit the photographer.